# Which is faster? Serving the image using PHP or the direct file?

Tags: php, image

I am developing a products website in which there are lots of images to be placed. To serve the images, which is the best method using PHP `imagejpeg()` or placing the image with it's direct path?

**Note**: The file in the storage is in high resolution say 1000 x 1000 pixels, and while display I may need to scale it using CSS.

At this juncture employing `imagecopyresampled` to scale the image in to required dimensions and display in the website is faster, I think. What is the fact?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see which is faster in your case?

Comment: I could not come to a judgement.

Comment: Why is that? Because the difference is too small? If that's the case, why don't you use the one that is easiest to implement?

Comment: Apache + file or Apache + PHP + file + resizing... hmm, which would possibly take more work to be done?

Comment: @deceze: I got this confusion when PageSpeed throws a suggestion "Serve scaled images"

Comment: Well yes, you should serve scaled images. That doesn't mean PHP needs to be involved in serving the image. Resize the image using PHP once, save it in the webroot and then let Apache serve it directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can resize image in php, and cache result of resized image to use in next use

Answer (score 0):

better option is to resize the images to required resolution using PHP, and this will reduce the un-necessary quality(more than 72DPI) which make the deduction in file size and lets your images load faster.

Answer (score 0):

imagejpeg()
Note: JPEG support is only available if PHP was compiled against GD-1.8 or later.

If you scale it through PHP, that is for example using the GD library, all the file handling is already been taking care. You can use many functions, see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

CSS scaling is used when cross-platform scaling is preferred, but i do now know if that is your goal. You could better scale by GD when neccessary and use CSS for the final full resolution display. Using file_exists() is quite quick b2way.